# Did anything happen to the Vorlons after they assassinated Deathwalker?

Tags: babylon-5

In B5: Deathwalker (Season 1, Episode 9) the Vorlons assassinate the titular Dilgar scientist.

They did this pretty openly. Were there any diplomatic consequences of killing her for the Vorlons?

Comment: What use would a complaint be? The Vorlons would just shrug inside their encounter suits and just keep on doing whatever they felt like doing.

Comment: @Darren it's true, but the Vorlons did have at least a token diplomatic presence on the station which implied they were a little more invested in politics than a natural disaster like a hurricane.

Comment: And yet, if you've seen later into the series you will know that a natural disaster is a very pertintent simile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "*Deathwalker Affair*" was briefly referenced in the following season episode [*Eyes*](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Eyes). Apparently Sinclair didn't make a formal complaint.

> **Ari Ben Zayn:** *These Vorlons have been trouble since they arrived.*
>
> **Garibaldi:** *Yeah, well, they're like that. Real fun guys.*
>
> **Ari Ben Zayn:** *Yet Sinclair didn't protest their actions in the DeathWalker affair.*
>
> **Garibaldi:** *Protests are as much use with them as fairy wings on a cement truck.*

The response of the other nations isn't disclosed, but I think we can reasonably assume that the Narn and the League were pleased that she was dead, Londo looks positively gleeful and the Minbari probably couldn't care less since her death helps to cover up the involvement of the Wind Swords Clan.

Since the Dilgar themselves "*died when their sun went nova*" there's no-one around to make any complaints.

Answer (score 9):

The Narns wanted her secret, and the Centauri would rather she be dead before the Narns got it. The Narns would have preferred her dead before the Centauri got it (and were planning on killing her anyway once they got it from her). The Minbari would have been happy to have her dead so she couldn't publicly reveal she'd been sheltered by some of them since the Dilgar War. The humans on Babylon were ambivalent about her and certainly didn't mind a lot if something terrible happened to her, and they were facing a diplomatic crisis for offering her shelter. And the League ambassadors just wanted her dead.

Having the Vorlons take her out solves the problem for everyone.